# Abrir una sesión a un servidor a través de una conexión ssh con putty

Tags: php, ssh, putty

todavía soy nuevo a esto de las conexiones ssh. Tengo un servidor virtual Windows Server 2008 64 bits, que usa php 5.6.40 y no lo puedo reiniciar o apagar y prender. Otro servidor en la misma red está en un Itanium ia64 con HP-UX y lo que quiero es establecer una conexión desde una página PHP del servidor de windows al itanium, entrar con un nombre de usuario y contraseña y mantener la sesión iniciada para realizar cambios desde la página web que se actualizan en tiempo real en el itanium.

Los cambios van a ser más complejos, pero por ahora he estado intentando con comandos simples y no funcionan. Primero intenté con putty, si abro putty desde la computadora virtual funciona perfectamente para conectarme a itanium, pero cuando intentó agregarlo a un código de php, se queda cargando cuando entro a la direccion web, no me marca error ni nada, simplemente se queda cargando y nunca se abre.

```
$user = 'xxxxx'; 
$host = 'yyy.yyy.yy.yy';  
$pass = 'zzzzz';  

$executable = 'putty.exe';
$searchPaths = [
    'C:\putty'
];

$puttyPath = '';
foreach ($searchPaths as $path) {
    if (file_exists($path . '\\' . $executable)) {
        $puttyPath = $path . '\\' . $executable;
        break;
    }
}

if (empty($puttyPath)) {
    die("PuTTY executable no encontrado.");
}

$commands = <<<EOF
cd /datos/prueba1/alco
vi prueba2.tem
i
aaa
\033
:w
:q
exit
EOF;

file_put_contents("bash.sh", $commands);

$logFile = 'putty_output.log';
$puttyCommand = "start \"PuTTY\" /B \"$puttyPath\" -ssh $user@$host -pw $pass -t -m bash.sh > \"$logFile\" 2>&1";
exec($puttyCommand);

unlink('bash.sh');
?>
```

Por lo que intenté no usar putty, y si se carga pero me dice que no tengo sshpass, sshpass no es reconocido como un comando interno o externo, y no lo puedo instalar ya que no puedo reiniciar el servidor:

```
<?php
$server = 'xxx.xxx.xx.xx';  
$username = 'yyyyy';
$password = 'zzzzz';

$commands = [
    'cd /datos/prueba1/alco',
    'vi prueba2.tem',
    'i',
    'aaa',
    "\033", 
    ':w',
    ':q',
    'exit'
];

$sshCommand = 'sshpass -p ' . $password . ' ssh -v -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ' . $username . '@' . $server . ' ';

foreach ($commands as $command) {
exec($sshCommand . '"' . $command . '" 2>&1', $output, $returnStatus);
print_r($output); 
echo $returnStatus; 

    if ($returnStatus !== 0) {
        echo 'No se pudo executar el comando';
        break;
    }
}
?>
```

¿Hay alguna alternativa para que pueda enviar comandos que funcionen?

Comment: primero que todo es super facil hacerlo en lenguajes como python que te entregan control sobre el sistema y pueden generar coneciones http (emular servidor apache), pero solo con php es mas complicado ya que debes otorgarle los permisos adecuados al putty para que el php pueda generar bien las conecciones, aparte que php es de ejecucuin rapida no constante por lo que mantener la session abierta no seria posible de manera simple, alli siempre lo mejor es abrir sesion enviar comandos y luego volver a cerrar la sesion ya que por defecto php tiene un tiempo de ejecucion por script de 30 segundos.

Comment: Hechale un vistazo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270419/how-to-execute-ssh-commands-via-php

Comment: Ok, supongo que puedo aprender python después, pero por ahora como envió commandos si no tengo sshpass?

Comment: Usa https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib ;)

Comment: Funciona con phpseclib1, pero ahora necesito un comando para poder buscar texto en el archivo del servidor al que me conecto y reemplazarlo, haciendo esto solo agrega texto al final del archivo: $newText = "aaa";
$ssh->exec('echo "' . $newText . '" >> /datos/prueba1/alco/prueba2.tem');

Answer (score -1):

Si estás buscando una alternativa para ejecutar comandos `SSH` desde `PHP` sin utilizar *PuTTY* o *sshpass*, puedes considerar la extensión `ssh2` de `PHP`. Esta extensión proporciona funciones para establecer una conexión SSH y ejecutar comandos en un servidor remoto.

Para utilizar la extensión ssh2, debes asegurarte de que esté instalada y habilitada en tu servidor. A continuación, te muestro un ejemplo de cómo usarla para ejecutar comandos SSH desde PHP (es un poco viejito el codigo, asique evalualo bien antes de implementarlo):

```
$server = 'xxx.xxx.xx.xx';
$username = 'yyyyy';
$password = 'zzzzz';

$connection = ssh2_connect($server);
if ($connection === false) {
    die('No se pudo establecer la conexión SSH');
}

if (!ssh2_auth_password($connection, $username, $password)) {
    die('Error de autenticación SSH');
}

$commands = [
    'cd /datos/prueba1/alco',
    'vi prueba2.tem',
    'i',
    'aaa',
    "\033",
    ':w',
    ':q',
    'exit'
];

foreach ($commands as $command) {
    $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, $command);
    stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
    $output = stream_get_contents($stream);
    fclose($stream);
    
    echo $output;
}
```

Fijate en detalle la implementacion de la función [ssh2_connect()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-connect.php) para establecer una conexión SSH con el servidor remoto. Luego, se autentica utilizando [ssh2_auth_password()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-auth-password.php) con el nombre de usuario y la contraseña proporcionados.

Después, se recorren los comandos que deseas ejecutar y se utiliza [ssh2_exec()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-exec.php) para ejecutar cada comando en el servidor remoto. Luego, se lee la salida del comando utilizando [stream_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-contents.php) y se muestra en la página.

Recuerda que para utilizar la extensión ssh2, debes asegurarte de tenerla instalada y habilitada en tu servidor. También es posible que necesites tener los módulos [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/) y [libssh2](https://www.libssh2.org/) instalados en el servidor.

Espero que esta alternativa te sea útil.